# Launching a SQL Server report using a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I am new to SSRS and have been tasked with creating a stored procedure that will execute a report that I have already created. The report will need to generate as a PDF and go to a folder `Z:\Reports`. I have no idea how to go about doing this.

Can anyone give me some direction most of my searches come up people attempting to create a report with a stored procedure, I just want to generate a PDF with one that I have already created.

Comment: Can't you just use the subscription stuff with the SSRS web management portal?  I remember you can just add a report to execute at a certain time and have the delivery mechanism be the file share.  Google around for SSRS subscriptions.

Comment: Is this what you're attempting to do? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2a1d6486-4524-48d4-86db-73af6b6e06c8/calling-a-report-from-tsql?forum=sqlreportingservices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a subscription to the report then run this SQL to get the GUID of the report

```
SELECT c.Name AS ReportName, rs.ScheduleID AS JOB_NAME
,s.[Description], s.LastStatus, s.LastRunTime
FROM 
      ReportServer..[Catalog] c 
      JOIN ReportServer..Subscriptions s ON c.ItemID = s.Report_OID 
      JOIN ReportServer..ReportSchedule rs ON c.ItemID = rs.ReportID
      AND rs.SubscriptionID = s.SubscriptionID
```

Create a sql agent job
Add the following SQL to the SQL Agent step replacing the GUID with the one from the above query

```
USE msdb 
EXEC sp_start_job @job_name = ‘1D2C91A5-8A86-4CDA-9F1B-442C4F6E450A'
```